# Swift return Self in callback

Tags: swift, inheritance

Is it possible to return Self in a super class method in Swift:
For example:

```
public class C {
    let name: String
    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    public class func getByID(id:String, cb:(C->Void)) {
        // do something async
        cb( C(name: "Some name") )
    }
}

class CC: C {
}

CC.getByID("someId") { c in
    if let c = c as? CC {
        // I want this to happen
        println("c is of type CC")
    } else {
        println("c is not of type CC")
    }
}
```

If I replace cb type to (Self->Void) I get a compile error saying

`'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method; did you mean 'C'?`

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. If `cb` was of type `Self -> Void`, you couldn't pass it a `C` like your example.

Answer (score 1):

In class method, you can use `self` as the class itself.

And, in this case, you need to mark your initializer as `required`.

```
public class C {
    let name: String
    required public init(name:String) {
//  ^^^^^^^^ HERE    
        self.name = name
    }

    public class func getByID(id:String, cb:(C->Void)) {
        // do something async
        cb( self(name: "Some name") )
        //  ^^^^ HERE
    }
}
```

---

ADDED:

> But is there any way to avoid downcasting to class CC in callback?

It's difficult, because we cannot use `Self` in the type of the parameters.

The best we can is something like this:

```
public class C {
    let name: String
    required public init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    public class func getByID<T: C>(id:String, cb:(T -> Void)) {
        if let instance = self(name: "Some name") as? T {
            cb(instance)
        }
        else {
            // `self` is not the type the callback expecting.
            // error handling if required.
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call:

```
CC.getByID("someId") { (c: CC) in
    println("c is of type CC")
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you.
But is there any way to avoid downcasting to class CC in callback?